# Google translate api set target language

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I am using google translate api for my web project. 
I want that I can limit the target language in the section where all language are showing 
My code is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                //$('.skiptranslate').style.display = 'none';
          new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I want that instead of showing all languages it should show 4 languages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dear you can do this thing when you are going to create website all that process here before getting code they asking you how may languages that u want to enable so please go thorugh again and check that option. i am pasting screen shot that when you will go to second step plugin setting here u can see option for specific languages hope that would be helpful for that what you want exactly.

[image: Specific Language Option]